# How to add scrollview in a best way for optimize screen size designed for 4 inch compatible with 3.5 inch?

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I have searched the post before I submit this question.
[How to optimize screen size designed for 4 inch compatible with 3.5 inch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20632039/how-to-optimize-screen-size-designed-for-4-inch-compatible-with-3-5-inch)

But above post does not answer my question.

Our designer send us 4 inch design UI, I use xib with autolayout to implement the design. And we're informed by the manager that we need to support 3.5 inch screen...

We do not want to creat another one xib to adapt the 3.5 inch screen, all we want to do is to add UIScrollView for the xib, is there anyboby have any idea to implement by this way and do not need to modify our exist xib layout constraints?

Comment: Why are you not using the Storyboard for it ? that would be easy to manage .

Comment: Use AutoLayout : https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/

Comment: @Aashish1aug thanks for you answer, but this project we already use xib not storyboard, is there any advise for xib?

Comment: @Mrunal , we have used auto layout, but our design is for 4 inch, it means that the screen height is much more higher than the 3.5 inch, so we need to add scroll view to make it scrollable.

Comment: Okay, Have you try to change the setting for Freefrom in Attribute inspector of your xib. As you are using Autolayout, I think it will be work with little bit correction.

Comment: ScrollView will not create any problem, As their scrolling will be depend only on their content view If you set size of content dynamically then it will work perfectly.

Comment: What is the issue with autolayout. It manages your UI in both 3.5 and 4 inch screen.

Comment: @Aashish1aug , the xib is 4 inch now, the auto layout constraints are added and work properly in 4 inch screen, but all I want to do is to make it scrollable in 3.5 inch screen.

Comment: Can you explain what type of constraints which have set for your content view in respective to super view(ScrollView)

Comment: May be their in some problem in constraints of content view.
your reference check this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26742230/uiscrollview-in-storyboard-not-working-with-ios-8-size-classes-and-autolayout

Comment: @agent_stack no, because our designer give us 4 inch screen design, the screen height is 568pt, and the design can not be cut in vertical direction.

Comment: @MellongLau I mean add scrollview with autolayout and give autolayout to its content too. So whats the problem doing this.

Comment: @agent_stack the problem is there are a lot of xib need to be modified, I need the approach that do less thing and make all xib scrollable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way around.

- Select all your view objects from your xib or storyboard scene
- In *Xcode menu > Editor > Embed In > View*
- Select again the newly added *View* (referring it as *ContainerView*)
- Add the *ContainerView* into a *ScrollView* using *Xcode menu > Editor > Embed In > Scroll View*
- Now adjust all your constraints for your inner most view objects related to ContainerView
- Keep the *ContainerView* height normal even if it goes beyond screen height
- Adjust top level *ScrollView* height connected with screen bounds.
- In codebase, set the *ScrollView ContentSize = ContainerView.frame.size*

Reference:

[image]

So your view hierarchy would look like this:

```
Default Controller View (UIView)
    |- Scroll View (UIScrollView)
        |- Container View (UIView)
            |- Other ViewObjects like UILabel,
            |- UIButton,
            |- UIImageView, etc.
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot, your approach is very good, but as `agent_stack` mention, it is a lot work if we change all xib in this way, so, do you have any other way to do this, something like just add some code to hack it?

Comment: @MellongLau  If you already have your View ready for 4 inch design, then you just copy that view, paste it under a scrollView and set scrollview's constraints and content size in code. Because I guess you must have set all your constraints and all for the objects inside that view. But yes, if you have multiple xibs / scenes, then you have to repeat these steps for all of them.

Comment: thanks for your help, I will receive your answer if there is no better answer here.

Comment: @MellongLau This is good approach. Once you done it then further you don't need to worry about for any other device it always run in iPhone 4s to iPhone 7+. Yeah it takes little bit time. But you can this smartly. Its all upto you now. You can get this [mine answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41185453/coordinates-of-last-element-in-scrollview/41185743#41185743) which can helps you achieve  your task, but don't forget to embed the UIView and UIScrollView as said by the Mrunal.

Answer (score 0):

Just add scroll view as parent view and check that all constraints is correct and system can calculate content size.

Comment: add a scroll view as parent view will need to update all constraints in xib, we have a lot of xibs...